# Using Java Stream in specific case with mapping and filtering response codes

Tags: java, selenium, lambda, java-stream

My question is regarding lambda with JAVA8 and use of the filters.
It is done via Selenium of Java for testing for different response codes.

How can I use Lambda in greatest possible way to transform following function with Streams?

The code which I wanted to refactor is as follows into Streams , lambda of Java 8:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
        if (!(links.get(i).getAttribute("href") == null) && !(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").equals(""))) {
            // Find HTTP Status-Code
            try {
                statusCode = getResponseCode(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").trim());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Check broken link
            if (statusCode== 404) {
                System.out.println("Broken of Link# "+i+" "+links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
            else if (statusCode== 400) {
                System.out.println("Bad Request# "+i+" "+links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
            else if (statusCode== 401) {
                System.out.println("Unauthorized# "+i+" "+links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
            else if (statusCode== 403) {
                System.out.println("Forbidden# "+i+" "+links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
            else if (statusCode== 500) {
                System.out.println("Internal server error# "+i+" "+links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
        }

    }
```

What I have for now is:

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String,Integer>> variablename =
    links.stream().map(WebElement::getAttribute("href"));
```

I was trying to do something along the lines of filtering out everything that is not 500,403,401,400,404  and only keeping the mapping or a Pair of that like (linkString, responseCode), but I am having a bit of troubles exactly how I could do it properly with Lambda?

EDIT1:
I didn't meant to put everything via stream, just to make as much use of it as I can in this example

Comment: Must your filter be specific to these error codes, or could it use ranges? (2xx & 3xx responses are generally considered success return codes, while 4xx & 5xx are error return codes). This would make the code shorter while being possibly more generic.

Comment: Do you want to keep your `System.out` calls?

Comment: I think using just ranges should be perfect, since as you mention 4xx & 5xx are error return codes. @Aaron

Comment: And to @MrWiggles I did plan to replace System.out later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple if you take it piece by piece, so:

```
// create a set of codes you want to include
Set<Integer> acceptableCodes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(404, 400, 401, 403, 500)); 

// for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
links.stream()

// convert to the href value as that's all we need later on
.map(link -> link.getAttribute("href"))

// filter out anything without a href
//   if (!(links.get(i).getAttribute("href") == null) && !(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").equals(""))) {
.filter(href -> href != null)
.filter(href -> !href.equals(""))

// filter out non-matching status codes
.filter(href -> acceptableCodes.contains(getResponseCode(href))
.map(link -> new LinkWithCode(href , getResponseCode(href))
.collect(toList());
```

Putting it together without the comments so you can read it easier:

```
Set<Integer> acceptableCodes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(404, 400, 401, 403, 500)); 
links.stream()
    .map(link -> link.getAttribute("href"))
    .filter(href -> href != null)
    .filter(href -> !href.equals(""))
    .filter(href -> acceptableCodes.contains(getResponseCode(href))
    .map(link -> new LinkWithCode(href , getResponseCode(href))
    .collect(toList());
```

`LinkWithCode` is a class you'll need to create to hold the link and the status code.  This assumes `getResponseCode` isn't a heavyweight operation as it's happening twice.

Caveat: I haven't tested this or put it in an IDE so you might have some tidy up to do.